# Do I need to lock around a const container with non-const elements?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, locking, deadlock

I've developed a multi-threaded application (developed in C++) that has various collections in which the containers (vectors, maps, etc) are const upon initialization, but the elements in the containers are not const.

I'm wondering if I need to hold a lock the entire time while retrieving an element from the container and reading/writing to it, or if just locking when reading/writing to it is enough... I'm just trying to resolve/avoid some deadlock issues, which would be solved if I didn't have to hold a lock while iterating the collection.

Here is a simple example, my question in this example is around the locking procedures for the GetObject & AdjustValue functions. If this was a multi-threaded application, I would ideally only like to lock when calling AdjustValue and ONLY when adjusting the data of a specific element in the collection. I think this would be okay, since the collection is const (objects are not added, removed, or deleted once the collection is populated).

**CustomClass.h**

```
class CustomClass
{
public:
   CustomClass() : 
      m_value(0)
   {

   }

   int m_value;
};
```

**CustomCollection**

```
#include "CustomClass.h"
#include <vector>

class CustomCollection
{
public:
   CustomCollection() : 
      m_collection(CreateCustomCollection())
   {

   }

   CustomClass* GetObject(
      const size_t index)
   {
      // Should I lock here, or since the collection is const can I avoid locking?
      if(index >= 0 && index < m_collection.size())
      {
         return m_collection[index];
      }

      return nullptr;
   }

   void AdjustValue()
   {
      // Do I need to lock before calling GetObject?
      // Since the collection is const, can I lock only when adjusting the values of the object itself?
      CustomClass* custom_object = GetObject(0);
      if(custom_object)
      {
         // Ideally I only need to lock here since the collection is const, just not the objects.
         custom_object->m_value++;
      }
   }
private:
   static const std::vector<CustomClass*> CreateCustomCollection()
   {
      std::vector<CustomClass*> collection;
      collection.push_back(new CustomClass());

      return collection;
   }

   const std::vector<CustomClass*> m_collection;
};
```

Comment: `// Ideally I only need to lock here` <-- yes, and no. If `AdjustValue` is the only place where you modify your elements, then you will avoid race condition. You will also prevent the application from modifying different elements under different indices at the same time (maybe too strict?). If however `GetObject` can b called independently in some other parts of your code, then it's up to that code to provide synchronization.

Comment: Btw `size_t` cannot be less than zero, it is unsigned so `index >= 0` is pointless

Comment: Re, "...but the elements in the containers are not const." The "elements" in your container are not `CustomCollection` objects. The elements are _pointers_ to `CustomCollection` objects,\* and those pointers never change. \[\*Well, actually, just _one_ object in your example, but of course it could have been any number of them.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_collection` is effectively a constant object, itself, that never gets modified after it is constructed. As such, no locking is required to access this container.

```
         // Ideally I only need to lock here since the collection is const, just not the objects.
         custom_object->m_value++;
```

Correct, if `m_value` is accessed from multiple execution threads then all access to `m_value` must be properly synchronized.